# Extra Unknown endpoints getting added to spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, endpoints

I am creating a spring boot application. I am adding few endpoints to it. In that process some of the endpoints are secure and some are not.

Once the application is installed I am getting some extra endpoints giving application info which are not even exposed.

Example: 
Some of the exposed endpoints are

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/category/v1")
public class ControllerClass {
     @RequestMapping(value="/pillars", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String pillarGetMethod() {
       //method
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/frameworks", method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public String frameworkGetMethod() {
       //method
     }
}
```

Now expectation is we will have

- /category/v1/pillars
- /category/v1/frameworks

should get exposed.

But with that

- /pillars
- /frameworks

is also getting exposed with response as

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "pillars" : [ {

    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://<ip>/pillars{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://<ip>/profile/pillars"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://<ip>/pillars/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 5,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I need help on understanding the output and also how I can stop this from getting exposed.

Comment: Did you define something like PillarRepository and Framework classes extending CrudRepository? If so, the underlying resources are automatically exposed by Spring Boot/Spring Data Rest, unless you annotate the repositories with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Marc. It solved the issue. Please add the response as answer, I will be very happy to accept the answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you defined something like :

```
public class PillarRepository extends CrudRepository<Pillar, String> { ... }

public class FrameworkPillarRepository extends CrudRepository<Pillar, String> { ... }
```

If so, the underlying resources are exposed automatically by Spring Boot/Spring Data Rest, unless you annotate the repositories with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`.

If you just wish to reproduce the automatic GET behavior, but with a custom path, use the [path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html#path--) option.